# Prove that the given property of the fibonacci number directly from the definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

$F(n)= 3F(n-3)+2F(n-4)$ for $n \ge 5$.

I just don't understand the whole process of this, my instructor has a rather weird way of explaining and I couldn't understand. 
can someone help me understand the process of this.

Comment: $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}=(F_{n-2}+F_{n-3})+F_{n-2}=2F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}=2(F_{n-3}+F_{n-4})+F_{n-3}=3F_{n-3}+2F_{n-4}$

Answer (score 2):

$F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$

$F(n-1)=F(n-2)+F(n-3)$

$F(n-2)=F(n-3)+F(n-4)$

Plug equation (2) and (3) into equation (1), we get $F(n)=F(n-2)+F(n-3)+F(n-2)=2*F(n-2)+F(n-3)=2*(F(n-3)+F(n-4))+F(n-3)=3*F(n-3)+2*F(n-4)$

Answer (score 0):

This is typically proven using the strong form of induction: proof that the equation holds for some base case(s), then use the definition to prove the equation for n assuming it holds for all numbers less than n.

Answer (score 0):

Induction should work. Base case $n = 5, F_5 = 5; 3F_2 + 2F_1 = 3\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 1 = 3+2 = 5 = F_5$. Thus its true for $n = 5$. Assume its true for $5 \leq n < k+1$, then $F_{k+1} = F_k+F_{k-1} = (3F_{k-3} + 2F_{k-4})+ (3F_{k-4} + 2F_{k-5}) = 3(F_{k-3}+F_{k-4})+2(F_{k-4}+F_{k-5})=3F_{k-2} + 2F_{k-3}$. Thus its true for all $n \geq 5$.

Answer (score 0):

The "2" and "3"
in
$F(n)= 3F(n-3)+2F(n-4)
$
may look familiar.

They come from this generalization:

For $n \ge k$,
$F(n)= F(k)F(n-k+1)+F(k-1)F(n-k)
$.

As usual,
the proof is by induction,
in this case
on $n$
for fixed $k$.
Since the result
depends on *two* preceding values,
the base step requires
two steps.

If
$n=k$,
this is
$F(k)
= F(k)F(1)+F(k-1)F(0)
= F(k)\cdot 1+F(k-1)\cdot 0
=F(k)
$,
which is true.

If
$n=k+1$,
this is
$F(k+1)
= F(k)F(2)+F(k-1)F(1)
= F(k)\cdot 1+F(k-1)\cdot 1
= F(k)+F(k-1)
=F(k+1)
$,
which is also true.

Suppose
$n \ge k+2$
and the result is true
for all $m$ such that
$k \le m < n$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
F(n)
&= F(n-1)+F(n-2)
\qquad\text{(fundamental Fibonacci recurrence)}\\
&= (F(k)F(n-k)+F(k-1)F(n-k-1))\\
&\quad+(F(k)F(n-k-1)+F(k-1)F(n-k-2))
\qquad\text{(induction hypothesis)}\\
&= F(k)(F(n-k)+F(n-k-1))\\
&\quad+F(k-1)(F(n-k-1)+F(n-k-2)))
\qquad\text{(regroup)}\\
&= F(k)F(n-k+1)+F(k-1)F(n-k)+F(n-k-1)
\qquad\text{(fundamental Fibonacci recurrence, twice)}\\
\end{array}
$

and we are done.

As is often the case in my answers,
nothing here is original.
However,
I enjoyed working it out
as I entered it.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has helped answer this